# Problems with bluetooth

Tags: settings, wingpanel, system, bluetooth

For over a month I have a problem with bluetooth.
I couldn't turn it on from wingpanel icon, but it was possible to do that from System Settings.
However, after bluetooth was turned on, I couldn't connect to device via *System Settings* tab and I could connect to it only choosing device from wingpanel icon.

Moreover, this week after update, I lost completely Bluetooth in *System Settings* (there is no icon) and when I click wingpanel icon and go to *Bluetooth Settings...* it opens bluetooth tab, but turning bluetooth on doesn't work.

Now the only way to turn my bluetooth on is with terminal `bluetooth on` command.
Probably I should be happy that my bluetooth works at all, but this system should be simple and beautiful so I'd like to have this simplicity.

Comment: I have the same issue. I `upgrade`d my system and the bluetooth setting was gone from system settings. I used `apt list --upgradable` before upgrading from the AppCenter and the list showed me that `switchboard-plug-gcc-bluetooth` will be uninstalled. I upgraded because I thought the elementary guys were going to push the new update later.

Comment: After This month update my icon came back to system settings. However Bluetooth settings doesn't work - I can't turn Bluetooth on

Answer (score 1):

Most of your issues are [known bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth).

About the missing bluetooth icon on system settings... try installing it:

```
sudo apt install switchboard-plug-bluetooth
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I have Bluetooth icon on wingpanel. Reinstalling also make no difference. :(

Comment: see my edit and try that. i didn't understand your question correctly.

Comment: Ok. It does not work.

Comment: Did you add any ppa? like the elementary daily ppa? your issue is so weird that only something like that could explain it.

Comment: No, it appeared after Elementary base update

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems that adding tlp or laptop Mode tools will disable or cripple bluetooth. I comfirmed with both of those apps. Once I removed those utilities bluetooth worked like a charm after a restart.

The issue with this is that if you want a decent battery use on your laptop you need to use either one of these tools. Yikes!! Not sure why this happens though as using these utilities should not affect bluetooth. If someone could verify my findings would be great.

I'm using a Lenovo Z-50 laptop. Here is my dmesg output.

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

[    2.023155] usb 4-2: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   29.665116] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   29.665149] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   29.665157] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   29.665163] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   29.665173] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   30.152299] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   30.152308] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   30.577370] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   48.374181] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   48.374188] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   48.374197] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  108.796222] Modules linked in: ctr ccm bnep binfmt_misc rtsx_usb_ms memstick wl(POE) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common kvm_amd kvm videodev media irqbypass arc4 rtl8723be joydev input_leds serio_raw btcoexist btusb btrtl fam15h_power rtl8723_common snd_hda_codec_conexant rtl_pci snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel rtlwifi snd_hda_codec mac80211 snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi btbcm snd_seq_midi_event edac_mce_amd cfg80211 btintel k10temp snd_rawmidi snd_seq bluetooth edac_core snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore i2c_piix4 shpchp ideapad_laptop sparse_keymap wmi 8250_fintek mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 drbg ansi_cprng algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb hid_generic usbhid hid amdkfd
[  114.811473] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  114.811489] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  114.811501] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11